# Default return value in recursion

Tags: c++, c, recursion

Consider the following well known code to find factorial of a number.

```
int fact(int num)
{
    if (num != 1)
        return num * fact(num - 1);
    else
        return num;
}
```

Now consider one more variant of the same

```
int fact(int num)
{
    if (num != 1)
        return num * fact(num - 1);
}
```

The first one looks clean, and if we give num as 4, it'll be `4*3*2*1`. The second one is also working fine, even though compiler may give a warning. But in the latter one, there's no return statement if the `num` become 1. So how the calculation happens? The code will work only when it return 1 if the `num` is 1. Can anybody please explain what's happening here `4*3*2*x`. How x is returned as 1. Thanks.

Edit: I'm using gcc 4.8.2

Comment: "The second one will also works fine, even though compiler may give a warning." - nonsense, that's badly broken.  For example, `fact(3)` returned 0 for me [at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/2ppyTM).  If it ever worked for you, it was a coincidence - the (accumulator) register or stack address where the `fact(1)` result was expected *happened* to have 1 in it as a side effect of prior processing.  Undefined behaviour is unpredictable and can coincidentally happen to work once in a while....

Comment: I'm using gcc. So far I'm getting correct result for any number I enter. That's why I got wonder and posted this question.

Comment: Sometimes you get lucky or perhaps unlucky that UB gave the correct result that it made you think this is the correct thing to do. Never rely on UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second variant is incorrect, there is no such thing as "default return value", that behavior is totally undefined!

Think about it, how will the compiler to know that `fact(1) == 1`??

If you let me guess, I'll say you wanted to avoid using the `else` stuff and, in that case, the default return value should be the last sentence.

```
int fact(int num)
{ // pre: num > 0
    if (num != 1)
        return num * fact(num - 1); 
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The second piece of code is incorrect, the warning that you thought is not important might be something like:

> warning: control reaches end of non-void function

You must provide the return value in all paths, otherwise (when `num` is `1`) it's undefined behavior, there's no *default return value* (with the exception of `main`).

Comment: Can you please explain how gcc doing this stuff. I'm getting the correct result for any number I enter.

Comment: @Sarath Don't try to dig into undefined behavior, it's pointless, even if you seem to get the *correct* result, you never know if it works the next time, on a different machine, or a different compiler, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is an undefined behavior, which means that the result totally depends on the specific compiler. Hence I think you should try to avoid it.